# Excel VBA merge multiple columns into one on separate rows

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I have an excel 2007 worksheet open with 5 colums and +/-5000 rows of data.

What I want to do is create a macro that will:

1. insert 3 blank rows under each record
2. copy the value in that row on column 1 and paste it in the 3 new rows in column 1
3. CUT the value from column 3 and place it in the first blank row beneath it in column 2
4. CUT the value from column 4 and place it in the next blank row beneath it in column 2
5. CUT the value from column 5 and place it in the next blank row beneath it in column 2

I am pulling out my hair trying to accomplish this but to no avail! please could someone assist me with this?

Much thanks

Comment: Show us what you have done so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim range As range
Dim i As Integer

Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim ColumnCount As Integer
Dim sheet As worksheet
Dim tempRange As range
Dim valueRange As range
Dim insertRange As range

    Set range = Selection
    RowCount = range.Rows.Count
    ColumnCount = range.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        Set sheet = ActiveSheet

        Set valueRange = sheet.range("A" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 1), "E" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 1))

        Set tempRange = sheet.range("A" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 2), "E" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 2))
        tempRange.Select
        tempRange.Insert xlShiftDown
        Set insertRange = Selection
        insertRange.Cells(1, 1) = valueRange.Cells(1, 1)
        insertRange.Cells(1, 2) = valueRange.Cells(1, 3)
        valueRange.Cells(1, 3) = ""

        Set tempRange = sheet.range("A" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 3), "E" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 3))
        tempRange.Select
        tempRange.Insert xlShiftDown
        Set insertRange = Selection
        insertRange.Cells(1, 1) = valueRange.Cells(1, 1)
        insertRange.Cells(1, 2) = valueRange.Cells(1, 4)
        valueRange.Cells(1, 4) = ""

        Set tempRange = sheet.range("A" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 4), "E" & (((i - 1) * 4) + 4))
        tempRange.Select
        tempRange.Insert xlShiftDown
        Set insertRange = Selection
        insertRange.Cells(1, 1) = valueRange.Cells(1, 1)
        insertRange.Cells(1, 2) = valueRange.Cells(1, 5)
        valueRange.Cells(1, 5) = ""

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Umm...sorry I had forgotten this earlier and I'd hate to ask but how would you then insert an "entry number" in the 3rd column?  Now that we have 4 rows for each original record, how would each of those recordsets show "1,2,3,4" ??
I tried modifying your code but botched it up a little :(

Comment: Nevermind...got it working now! thnaks again for the assist!!

Answer (score 2):

Pass the worksheet to this particular function. It's not a complicated thing to do - I'd be interested to know what was going wrong with your approaches (it would have been good to post sample code in your question).

```
Public Sub splurge(ByVal sht As Worksheet)

    Dim rw As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For rw = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        With sht
            Range(.Rows(rw + 1), .Rows(rw + 3)).Insert
            For i = 1 To 3
                ' copy column 1 into each new row
                .Cells(rw, 1).Copy .Cells(rw + i, 1)
                ' cut column 3,4,5 and paste to col 2 on next rows
                .Cells(rw, 2 + i).Cut .Cells(rw + i, 2)
            Next i
        End With
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Joel! sorry i didnt refresh the page so didnt see ur post. Thank u however for the effort.  I will nonetheless try this out! thank u!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT t.F1, t.Col2 FROM (" _
       & "SELECT F1, 1 As Sort, F3 As Col2 FROM [Sheet1$] " _
       & "UNION ALL " _
       & "SELECT F1, 2 As Sort, F4 As Col2 FROM [Sheet1$] " _
       & "UNION ALL " _
       & "SELECT F1, 3 As Sort, F5 As Col2 FROM [Sheet1$] ) As t " _
       & "ORDER BY F1, Sort"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Hi Remou! same as with Joel above...didnt see these 2 additional posts.  Thank u however for this, I've never seen SQL used in VBA before, so I'll try this out for curiousity! thank u!

Comment: Two *original* posts :) Enjoy.

Comment: :$ yeah i noticed the submission times now. but the strange thing is that Astander's answer was the ONLY one when I refreshed the screen ????? weird!